# How to store and retrieve 4 sbyte values in a signed int

Tags: c#

Due to limitations in Unity serialization, I need to store 4 sbyte values in a single signed int. This is easy for me to do with unsigned integers, but when I try it with signed integers things get all wonky.

store in signed int => 0xFF (sbyte), 0xFF (sbyte), 0xFF (sbyte), 0xFF (sbyte)

(I get errors with the below code)

warning CS0675: The operator `|' used on the sign-extended type`int'. Consider casting to a smaller unsigned type first

error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `long' to`int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
    int data = datas[index];

    switch (offset)
    {
        case 0:
            data = unchecked ((data & 0x00FFFFFF) | ((byte) value << 24));
            break;
        case 1:
            data = unchecked ((data & 0xFF00FFFF) | ((byte) value << 16));
            break;
        case 2:
            data = unchecked ((data & 0xFFFF00FF) | ((byte) value << 8));
            break;
        case 3:
            data = unchecked ((data & 0xFFFFFF00) | (byte) value);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Invalid offset.");
    }
```

Comment: umm, how did you get 0xFF (255 decimal) into sbyte (-128 to 127)?

Comment: @kostyan msb is the signed bit.

Comment: @kostyan 0xFF interpreted as a signed byte is -1 in decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the significance of the values being signed. I understand you want to basically "concatenate" the bytes to form an int.

```
int i = unchecked (
 (byte)byte0 << 24 | (byte)byte1 << 16 | (byte)byte2 << 8 | (byte)byte3 << 0);
```

The cast to unsigned is necessary to avoid logical shifting behavior that treats the sign bit specially.

Comment: Won't casting a negative sbyte to byte throw a range exception? I think you have to wrap those casts in `unchecked()`.

Comment: @hatchet good point. Depends on compiler settings as well. Default is unchecked.

Comment: `int data = datas[index];
        
        switch (offset)
        {
         case 0:
          data = unchecked ((data & 0x00FFFFFF) | ((byte) value << 24));
          break;
         case 1:
          data = unchecked ((data & 0xFF00FFFF) | ((byte) value << 16));
          break;
         case 2:
          data = unchecked ((data & 0xFFFF00FF) | ((byte) value << 8));
          break;
         case 3:
          data = unchecked ((data & 0xFFFFFF00) | (byte) value);
          break;
         default:
          throw new Exception("Invalid offset.");
        }`

Comment: please see revised question. I am trying to update the various parts of the int rather than set them all at once.

Comment: Your code is pretty good. Those errors are just trying to help you avoid mistakes. Silence them by casting the literals to the proper data type like this `(int)0xFF00FFFF`. Not sure where the warning is coming from. Maybe just add another cast somewhere. This bit fiddling is not exactly my specialty.